# Running multiple deferred groups sequentially

Tags: jquery, promise, jquery-deferred, pouchdb, .when

So I have been messing around with $.Deferred() and can't quite get it to work the way I want.

The idea is to run a group of 10 items, wait for it to finish, run the next group, wait for it to finish, etc.

The code below produces this output

```
(3)Item Complete
(30)Item Finished
```

.

```
indexedDB.deleteDatabase("_pouch_test")
db = new PouchDB('test');

function item(limit){
    var d = $.Deferred();
    var promises = []
    var url = ""//url that will respond with up to limit responces
    $.getJSON(url,function(data){
        $.each(data.items,function(i, item){
                promises.push( db.post({item:"test"}).then(console.log("Item Finished ")) )
        })
    }).fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
        var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
        console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
    });
    return $.when.apply($,promises).promise()
}

function group(times){
    var d = $.Deferred().resolve()
    for( var i=0; i<times; i++){
        d.then( item(10).then( function(){console.log("Group Complete")} ) )
    }
    return d.promise()
}

function init(){
    group(3).then("All Complete")
}
```

What I am expecting is output like

```
(10)Item Finished
Group Complete
(10)Item Finished
Group Complete
(10)Item Finished
Group Complete
All Complete
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction, that would be great. I'm thinking i'm doing the $.when incorrectly, but don't know another way.

Thanks Again.

--edit: After looking back over, I believe the promises array is empty when it is handed to $.when, still now sure how to fix it though.

--edit2: [updated code](http://pastebin.com/raw/cAU7Fj0g) produces output below, but "All complete" is being displayed first? It should be last.

```
All Complete
(10)Item finished
Group Finished
(10)Item finished
Group Finished
(10)Item finished
Group Finished
```

--edit3: [So I solved it](http://pastebin.com/raw/G0y0FRLF). I had to assign the updated deferred to the variable as well as wrap the inside of the then in a function. I'm sure the code could be more efficient, but it's a great starting point.

Comment: It's really confusing, but I think you're looking for something more like this -> https://jsfiddle.net/16s71q12/1/

Comment: @adeneo Something in there made me think of a solution to the empty promises in $.when problem. check edit2.

Comment: Do you want to run the items *in* each group of 10 sequentially or in parallel? I know you want the groups in sequence.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie  I have solved the problem (edit3). But the idea was like so. You have 3 groups of 10 items. Run the 10 items of group 1 in parallel and wait for them to finish. Now run the 10 in group 2 in parallel and wait for them to finish, etc. My solution feels sloppy, but gets the job done

Comment: If you solved your problem, [please post an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So ended up solving it.

1. I had to actually add a `console.log()` for the "All Complete" output.... yeah...
2. Promises were not being added to the promise array before the `$.when()` was run. I moved it into a `.then()` chained to the `.getJSON()`.
3. It seemed the `group()` function was resolving before it actually was. I had to set the deferred object to the changed one (`d = d.then()`), as well as encase the inside of the `.then()` in a function.

   ```
   indexedDB.deleteDatabase("_pouch_test");
   db = new PouchDB('test');

   function item(limit){
       var promises = [];
       var url = ""; //url to respond with up to limit responces
       var j = $.getJSON(url)
           .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
               var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
               console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
           })
           .then(function(data){
               var promises=[]
               $.each(data.items,function(i, item){
                       promises.push( db.post({item:"test"}).then(console.log("Item Finished ")) );
               });
               return $.when.apply($,promises)
           }).then(function(){
               console.log("Group Complete")
           })
           return j;
   }

   function group(times){
       var d = $.Deferred().resolve()
       for( var i=0; i<times; i++){
          d = d.then(function(){return item(10)} )
       }
       return d.promise()
   }

   function init(){
       group(3).done(function(){console.log("All Complete")})
   }
   ```

This outputs the following, which is as intended. Yay!

```
(10)Item Finished
Group Finished
(10)Item Finished
Group Finished
(10)Item Finished
Group Finished
All Complete
```